# How to make a domain receiving email behind cloudflare?

Tags: postfix, email-server, cloudflare

I have a web server hosting multiple domains (centos + postfix + dovcot), one of my domain  its dns is hosted on cloudflare (ie. abcd.com), but when I use gmail to send email to a user@abcd.com, user@abcd.com will not be able to receive the email. Here is the MX record I set in cloudflare:

```
Type   Name   Value                                       TTL          Active
mx     mail   handled by mail.abcd.com with priority10    Automatic     
cname  mail   is an alias of abcd.com                     Automatic    grey cloud
```

Any knows how can I make the domain receive the emails?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two distinct errors in your configuration:

1. The MX record should be for your domain, not for a subdomain.
2. An MX record should not point to a CNAME. Point it to a record with an IP address.

An example of a working domain:

[image: CloudFlare DNS settings]

Comment: i tested your config, but the email only can be received when the domain name(not mail) A record is in grey cloud (ie first row of your pic) , so it stills blocking my email

Comment: It's supposed to be a gray cloud.

Comment: but your pic yes-www.org A record is in orange

Comment: But that is _not_ the record that the MX record points to!

Comment: @hkguile Please do yourself a favour and find out what grey and orange clouds mean. mail is supposed to be grey because this means cloudflare does NOT CACHE THE CONTENT - it is not acting as a SMTP buffer. It does so for all websites (which is what a CDN does).

Comment: @TomTom I think he figured it out by now. I'm just editing some of my old stuff.