# DNS EMAIL errors in Cpanel and Cloudflare

Tags: domain-name-system, cloudflare, cpanel

I have a problem with my DNS records and cannot get an email to receive. MXtoolbox tells me DMARK is not set up but I added the records. It says I I have a problem with SMTP resolution.

Cloudflare Says "An MX record was not found for your root domain" and I have added one but still says I haven't

Can someone help figure this out? Below are screenshots of my setup

**Cloudflare**

[image: Cloudflare]

**Cpanel DNS**

[image: Cpanel DNS]

**Cpanel MX Entry**

[image: Cpanel MX Entry]

**MXtoolbox**

[image: MXtoolbox]

Comment: You haven't got an MX record for your domain name showing in CloudFlare. I'm not sure why you have posted cPanel DNS records, as they have no effect.

Comment: Hi Michael, I believe have an MX record in cloudflare - it is set-up as MX:mx:mail handled by mail.maridentours.com:Automatic. IS this not correct or do I need to add another for the domain itself?

Comment: Right, you set an MX record for a subdomain, not for your domain name.

Comment: Thanks Micheal - I changed it to MX : maridentours.com : mail handled by maridentours.com which I think is correct. MXtoolbox still reports fail to connect to SMTP

Comment: I'm pretty sure [this](https://serverfault.com/a/642956/126632) is what you need to do with CloudFlare. But we can't help you with cPanel.